# Is it possible to configure a helm chart to dynamically use a value based on another value?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

Is there any way to use helm logic to analyze the Kubernetes version, i.e. Capabilities.KubeVersion, then dynamically choose a value from a map of Kubernetes versions to values, something like

```
kubernetesVersionCompatibility:
    1.15:
       insertValue: foo
    1.18:
       insertValue: bar
```

Comment: Not that I know of. Helm templating doesn't query Kubernetes at any point, until applying your objects: you won't have local variables or facts, describing your cluster. Maybe use some makefile or whatever, checking your kube version before running the helm command, so you can fix your Values ...

Answer (score 6):

You can stitch together a couple of different parts to do that.

You've already found the [`.Capabilities` built-in object](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/).  You can use that to guard against, for instance, the Deployment version change in Kubernetes 1.16:

```yaml
{{- if .Capabilities.APIVersions.Has "apps/v1" }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
{{- else }}
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Deployment
```

I'd prefer this method to checking on the `.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version` if you can.

You can easily check for an *exact* match using the structure you show.  The core [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language includes an `index` function that can look up an arbitrary key in a dictionary:

```
{{- $v := index .Values.kubernetesVersionCompatibility .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Version }}
Insert the value {{ $v.insertValue }}
```

(You may need to force the keys to be strings `"1.15":`.)

There's not a convenient way to look up the highest version less than or equal to the current version.  If, say, a developer's kind cluster runs Kubernetes 1.20, the 1.18 values will most likely work, but that would have to be explicitly listed in the values.  A last resort could be hard-coding the values:

```
{{- if ge (int .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor) 18 }}
Insert the value bar
{{- else if ge (int .Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor) 15 }}
Insert the value foo
{{- else }}
Insert the value ???
{{- end }}
```

Comment: Using `ge` as comparison operator the type conversion is required, e.g. `{{- if ge (.Capabilities.KubeVersion.Minor|int) 18 }}`

Comment: Thanks, I've corrected this in the answer.  (In the [Go source](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/7838fb769d00f53c858d994a873f42c2960a7d25/pkg/chartutil/capabilities.go#L70-L75) these fields are strings.)